# Getting wrong messages for Android GCM push notifications

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have built 3 versions of the same app using the same code base but using different package names and layouts.

One of the features of my app is that it receives push notification messages.

Now, i have installed all 3 apps on my device. So when the push notification comes, i find that it invokes the GCMIntentService onMessage() method of all 3 apps??? Why is this happening? I am a confused. Because i have used different package names for my apps.

Because of this i get 3 notifications for a single notification from the server.

Please help!

Thanks!

Edit: I have confirmed the category from the intent parameter which each of the app receives when the onMessage is invoked. It seems to be receiving the correct category. Could this then be a issue from the server side?

Comment: you are probably using the same gcm info for all 3 apps, api key, sender ids etc

Comment: @PatrickEvans across the 3 apps the common part is the code base. However, the package names of the 3 apps is different. Also i have 3 registered APP keys on the google APIs site for each of these apps. I tried changing the name of the intent service in each of the apps but then the app stopped receiving the push notifications. It seems that the intent service has to be named GCMIntentService. Only the package name of the intent can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Each of your 3 apps registers to GCM separatelly, and should receive a different registration id, even if the same sender id is used for all three.

Therefore, a single message sent from the server should only teach one app. What I assume happened is that you used the same manifest definitions for all 3 apps. I'm referring to the GCM permissions and the intent service of the broadcast receiver. On older Android versions this would prevent GCM from working at all, but you are probably using an Android 4.x device,  in which these permissions are not enforced for some reason.

To fix the problem, use the correct package name in each app manifest.

Comment: although i have used the same code base for my 3 apps. I have made sure i have changed the package name (category) in the receiver of each of my apps. I tried changing the name of the intent service and the broadcast receiver from 'GCMIntentService' to some other value like 'GCMMyIntentService' but then the app stopped receiving notifications. So i had to revert to using the same name for the intent service but i have changed the package name in the receiver category for each of the apps. I am starting to assume it could be some issue from the server side?